# Just bought an electric car. Do I need a bigger panel?

Tags: electrical

[image][image]

I'm looking to add a 30amp 240v outlet about 15 feet away using 10-3 armored cable. Can I piggyback off of one of my AC compressors? (Left side 2nd breaker from the top and taking 4slots for 2 zone compressors) I lower the thermostat every night on one of them so I know only one or the other will turn on. I plan on only charging between midnight and 8am.

Comment: Hard to tell on my phone but if your AC is off you can add a additional load at night but what happens at night in the winter? We don't know your total loads in the summer it sounds great but in the winter when the winter if you have electric heat it could overload your service , more info is needed to fully answer this question.

Comment: The entire right side of this panel is multi-wire branch circuits (misc 120V circuits that are wired to share neutrals).

Comment: How big are your A/C units, how many square feet is your house, and how much power does the EV charger you plan on using draw?

Comment: Also, what wiring method is used for the existing homeruns to the A/C outdoor units?

Comment: It looks like you have a tap on the service feeders. Could you tell us where it goes? Is there a second main?

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician that's easy, the current transformer twisted pairs  disappearing into the same too-small conduit tell the story.  It's one of those home power monitors like Sense, Curb, Neurio etc.

Comment: Ed beal, I have central heating powered by natural gas. The ac breakers only power the compressor.

Comment: Threephaseeel, the ac units are rated for 17 amps and 18 Amps. The 17 amp unit cools 1500 sq ft and the 17 amp unit 750 sq ft. The ev charger is rated at 16 amps@240v

Comment: The tap on the service feeders go to grid tied solar panels

Comment: @Thekuai -- do you have space next to this for a subpanel?

Answer (score 1):

### If you have space alongside this panel (at least a full stud bay's worth to one side)...

If you have a full stud bay's worth of space to the left or right of this panel to mount another breaker panel, then mounting a second panel and using it as a *subpanel* is your best bet here.  A 24-space, 125A, main lug  Homeline subpanel (HOM2448L125PGC) is inexpensive, provides sufficient expansion space, and comes with a ground bar already fitted -- with this, a trio of 1AWG Al wires in a 2" rigid metal conduit nipple would connect a HOM2100 breaker + a LK125AN neutral lug on the neutral bar in the main panel to the main lugs in the subpanel, providing a 100A feed to the subpanel.

In this setup, the HOM2100 replaces one of the A/C breakers, and both A/C breakers move to the subpanel, with 10AWG pigtails through the conduit nipple connecting the hot wires from the A/C breakers to the existing wires out to the air conditioners.  The circuit to the car charger can then be run off a HOM220 breaker in the subpanel, and blank-out plates (HOMFP) installed in the empty spaces in the main panel.  The branch circuit neutrals would land on the neutral bar(s), while ground wires would land on the ground bar(s), and the green bonding screw would not be installed into the subpanel (or removed if it was installed at the factory).

### If you don't have room for a subpanel

If there is no space available for a subpanel, an alternative option would be to use a HOMT220230 quadruplex breaker instead of one of the A/C breakers -- the A/C circuit would land on the two 30A poles, while the car charger circuit would then land on the two 20A poles.  This is less expensive than a subpanel, but does not provide any expansion room, unlike the subpanel option -- I'd favor the subpanel in your case considering how full your main panel is.